# Migrate AddNLog from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

In the `Startup` class of my project I have the following `Configure` method:

```
private void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    ...
}
```

This worked OK in .NET Core 2.2, but after upgrading to 3.0, I get the warning `Method 'NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigureExtenstions.AddNLog' is obsolete: instead use ILoggingBuilder.AddNLog() or IHostBuilder.UseNLog().`

So I tried to update the method to

```
private void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    ...
    loggingBuilder.AddNLog();
    ...
}
```

or

```
private void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    ...
    hostBuilder.UseNLog();
    ...
}
```

But in both cases I got a DI exception: `Could not resolve a service of type {Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder} for the parameter {loggingBuilder/hostBuilder} of method 'Configure' on type 'MyProject.Startup'`.

I could not find any viable source on how to change the NLog configuration fro .NET Core 3.0 and there is nothing about logging in the [official Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure). Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: How about [NLog's documentation on the matter](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)?

Comment: I was looking at it, but was a little confused. There is no `AddNLog` method anywhere in the documentation and the logging initialization takes places in `Program.cs` instead of `Startup.cs`. Is this the new way of initilalizing NLog? If yes, the obsolete comment could be more detailed.

Comment: NetCore3 is the one that prevents you from adding extra parameters. See also: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9337 NLog.Extension.Logging just tries to guide you. If you have ideas for how to improve the guidelines, then please create pull-requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ASP.NET Core 2+, the pattern to bootstrap an ASP.NET Core site has changed. NLog adapts that. With the latest version of `NLog.Extensions.Logging.ConfigureExtenstions`, the old methods are made obsolete.

For example, ASP.NET Core nowadays uses a `CreateHostBuilder`.

I would recommend to follow:

1. [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0)
2. And then: [Getting started with ASP.NET Core 3 · NLog/NLog Wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)